# Can I get the ResourceMethodRegistry being used by Resteasy

Tags: java, reflection, jax-rs, resteasy

The ResourceMethodRegistry in Resteasy is used in resolving a HttpRequest to an actual method call for the uri, method, content type, etc in the request.  Is the actual populated instance of this registry that RestEasy is using available?

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
ResourceMethodRegistry registry = ResourceMethodRegistryFactory.getInstance();
ResourceMethod otherMethod = (ResourceMethod) registry.getResourceInvoker(myRequest);
```

The reason I would like to do this is to be able to get call "signatures" that are calculated based on annotations for the method I am trying to resolve in order to invalidate caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During deployment, the `ResourceMethodRegistry` is added to the  [`ServletContext`](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/11c1703eac82b9064058b6d8a99b25be47fd24d5/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/ResteasyBootstrap.java#L32). So you should be able to get it by doing this:

```
ResourceMethodRegistry registry =
          (ResourceMethodRegistry)context.getAttribute(Registry.class.getName());
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the quick response.  I also found that since I am in a PreProcessInterceptor I can inject it using @Context.